# How to Call Ajax from HTML/JS to start PHP Function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, submit

I'm working on a code that will show an alert when form is submitted and then redirect back to home page. If an empty form is submitted, I want to show an error alert. I realize that I cannot call PHP from onclick, and that I need to instead call a JS function that will start my PHP function. Can someone tell me if my PHP code is on the right track, and how to initialize the AJAX function? Trying to do this WITHOUT JQuery. Thanks!

html

```
<form method="POST" action="contact.php">

<label for='message'>Leave a Message:</label> <br><br>
   <textarea rows="15" cols="45" name="message" id="message" ></textarea> 
<br><br>
  <input type="submit" name='submit' value="send!" onclick="startajax()"/>

</form>
```

and php

```
<?PHP


$subject="New Message!";
$message=$_POST ["message"];

function leavemessage () {

if(!empty($_POST['message'])) {

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function error(){
alert("Error!");
window.location.replace=(contact.html);}
</script>';

}

else 

{


{mail ($email, $subject, $message, "From:".$from);}

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation(){
alert("Message Sent!");
window.location.replace (index.html);}
</script>';

}

}


?>
```

Comment: For starters you have syntax errors in your PHP.  At both location where you are doing `window.location.replace`. You need to ether use " on the outside that entire string and use the ' to use as quotes inside, or escape those single quotes surrounding the HTML file.

Comment: where's this function `startajax()`? or did you want us to write it for you?

Comment: i haven't written it yet, i am completely new to coding and i'm mainly wondering what needs to be changed in my php, but all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with jquery ajax to complete your request like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" id="contact-form" onsubmit="return startajax()" >

<label for='message'>Leave a Message:</label> <br><br>
   <textarea rows="15" cols="45" name="message" id="message" ></textarea> 
<br><br>
  <input type="submit" name='submit' value="send!"/>

</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?PHP


$subject="New Message!";
$message=$_POST ["message"];
if(!empty($message)) {
   //your email code here
   exit(json_encode(array('error' => 0, 'errorMessage' => '')));
} else {
   exit(json_encode(array('error' => 1, 'errorMessage' => 'Message is required')));

}


}


?>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
    var startajax = function(){
        var url = 'contact.php';
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "JSON",
            data : $('#contact-form').serialize(),
            success : function(response) {
                if (response.error == 0) { // success
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    alert('SUCCESS MESSAGE');
                } else { // error
                    alert(response.errorMessage);//form is invalid
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
    }


</script>
```

Just make sure you have `jquery` library included to your page.

**As per request**, Without jQuery code below:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" id="contact-form" action="contact.php" >

<label for='message'>Leave a Message:</label> <br><br>
   <textarea rows="15" cols="45" name="message" id="message" ></textarea> 
   <?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>
    <p style="color:red;">Message is required</p>
   <?php } ?>
<br><br>
  <input type="submit" name='submit' value="send!"/>

</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?PHP

    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
        $subject="New Message!";
        $message=$_POST ["message"];
        if(!empty($message)) {
           //your email code here
           echo '<script>window.location.href="index.html"</script>';
        } else {

           echo '<script>window.location.href="index.html?error=1"</script>';
        }


        }
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh! I really want to know how to do it without JQuery, but I may try this route as well.

Comment: Okay, let me post without jquery answer

Comment: Updated, try above edit code and let me know if you have any issue. Thanks

Comment: Okay, you can also mark this answer as helpful, so that it helps others too. Thanks

Comment: Hey Stone, please upvote it too. so that it comes first in search result and user who are facing the same issue will get the solution easily. Thanks